# Where is the src code point where Linux kernel establish mapping virtual-physical address?

Tags: linux, memory-management, linux-kernel, page-tables

As I know, when program try to access virtual address that the corresponding PTE is **NO** present , kernel will trigger page fault and page fault handler will handle it.

In handler, if fault is caused by no physical mapping to the PTE, kernel should allocate free physical page and write physical address to PTE.

I found many functions like `__handle_mm_fault` or `handle_pte_fault`, but I cannot find the location where kernel actually allocate physical page. Could anyone give some suggestion?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In kernel 3.18, the procedure is like this: `handle_mm_fault`->`handle_pte_falut`->`do_anonymous_page`->`alloc_zeroed_user_highpage_movable`

Comment: I review code in your path, but I cannot find code in which put physical  address to pte.

Comment: @KyL after calling `alloc_zeroed_user_highpage_movable`, a valid `page` is allocated, and then `mk_pte()` and `set_pte_at` are called to put physical address to pte entry and copy it to correct position of page table.

Answer (score 0):

The primary functions for page allocation are located in `mm/page_alloc.c`

The main function is `__alloc_pages()` (which is actually a macro calling `__alloc_pages_nodemask()` in current kernels).

The linux kernel uses a **zoned buddy allocator**:

- There are several zones for several types of memory (kernel/user memory, DMA, NUMA-related criteria, etc.)
- Pages are allocated in certain orders (i.e. order *n* are 2^n pages)
- At the beginning, high order blocks of free memory are available.
- If a chunk of the requested order is not available, try to split a bigger chunk or use several chunks of lower order to satisfy the request.
- If a chunk is freed, the allocater attempts to merge it with its `buddies` (i.e. the blocks, from which it was split on allocation) to replenish a higher-order chunk from it.

The freelist is the memory structure in which the free pages are stored. It is initialized depending on the architecture (i.e. for intel/amd in `arch/x86/mm/init_*.c`)